# java.lang.NullPointerException warning after setting image resource

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-support-library, android-image

After defining a rescource for the my imageview, a warning is then returned. What can be done to get rid of this warning?

```
    imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.map));
```

> Method invocation 'imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.map))' may produce 'jave.lang.NullPointerException'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning, so you can ignore it if you have no reason to think that the variables are null, but you can just `assert` that the variable isn't null like so to get rid of it.

```
assert imageView != null;
imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.map));
```

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception on a line of the form A.B.C means that something on the left-hand side of a dot is null. In this example :

either A is null;

or A.B is null.

There can be no other reason.

[From this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977856/android-caused-by-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Also You can check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Comment: You didn't answer how to get rid of the warning, you only explained why it happens.